# How to keep always work/listen queue in laravel and cpanel?

Tags: laravel, observers, laravel-queue

I use cpanel for hosting and I made a schedule that every minute call the `php artisan queue:listen --stop-when-empty` .

when I remove the `--stop-when-empty` the Physical Memory Usage goes to 100% and give error of allocate memory.

but I need to run queue for < always > because two customer should not be able to buy at the same time. I have a `BuyJob` that `implement ShouldQueue` and decrease Inventory.

is the best way to make a model and observer for job table and call the  `php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty` on `created()` event of observer ?

Answer (score 0):

yes if we direct run php artisan queue:work in cronjob then server memory issues comes.. you need to register this command in console folder kernel.php then register php artisan schedule:run in cronjob

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')
         ->everyMinute()
         ->withoutOverlapping();
```

[help source](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/using-queues-on-shared-hosting-with-laravel)

Comment: I don't want to stop the work. it is necessary to run the jobs immediately to update the 'inventory' field in database.